# Mounting a sql query by filtering data

Tags: sql

I'm trying to put together a report, where I need to list documents that have status as EXCLUDED. There are usually several records with the same NF but have multiple STATUS. I need to consider that always the last record of a certain NF has STATUS of EXCLUDED, if in case the last record of a certain NF is different from EXCLUDED, it should not appear in my report.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id,nf,status,date FROM documents
```

For example I have the following results:

[image]

how it should be:

[image]

can anybody help me?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The most efficient method is likely to vary by database vendor. Also to be clear, are you looking for the latest record for each "nf" where the status is "EXCLUDED", or where the latest record for each "nf" has a status of "EXCLUDED"? There is a subtle, but important difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, you want this:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), NF, Status, MAX(DATE)
FROM documents
WHERE status = 'EXCLUDED'
GROUP BY NF, Status
```

This makes assumptions based on your sample data.  If `DATE` or `ID` is not always increased sequentially it will not work.  There are other ways to do if that is the case, but otherwise this is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, NF, STATUS, MAX(DATE) AS DATE
FROM documents
WHERE STATUS = 'EXCLUDED'
GROUP BY NF, STATUS
```

This will give you:

[image: Result]

Comment: This will return the `5, 3, EXCLUDED` row that isn't in the desired results

Comment: You are correct. I missed that line when looking at the table.